# Center text with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am using the following css

```
#header {
 color: #333;
 width: 900px;
 float: left;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 height: 150px;
 margin: 10px 0px 5px 0px;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #CACACA 0%, #EFEFEF 100%);
}
```

I have 2 elements contained in a div.

```
<div id="header">
    <p:graphicImage value="/dbimages/#{accountManagedBean.imageId}" styleClass="imageResizeAccountInfo"/>
    <h:outputLabel value="#{accountManagedBean.account.userName}" style="font-size:40px"/> 
</div>
```

One is an image, and the other is text. I would like the image to be on the left, and the text to be vertically and horizontally centered.

The actual HTML that gets produced is this:

```
    <div id="header">
        <img id="mainForm:j_idt164" src="/ui/dbimages/2805" alt="" class="imageResizeAccountInfo" />
        <label style="font-size:40px">dvargo</label> 
    </div>
```

Currently they are right next to each other. I am new to css and have created this using composition so far.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please show your ACTUAL HTML.

Comment: @Diodeus I have updated the question to show the produced HTML as well

Comment: Anyone else find it amusing that a default-username person "user489041" has 4722 SO points?  It's the little things.

Answer (score 2):

You already have the width and height set on your `div`, so the following additional CSS rules will allow your div to accept vertical alignment for its content, i.e., your text.

```
display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle
```

You can use `float: left` or `position: relative; top: xxx; left: xxx;` on your image to position it to the left by floating, or to left relative to the top left of the div by a precise amount. Another good solution is to use the image as the background of the div (with `no-repeat`), and then using `padding-left` on your div element to make room for the image.

JS Fiddle: example (with a cute smiley face image since I don't have the OP's original image): http://jsfiddle.net/wCpfs/

Comment: @RitabrataGautam I sympathize! I've been in the same situation as you so many times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `line-height` property to center the text vertically.
As well as using `text-align:center` will make your text move to the center.

Try this or something similar:

```
#header {
   text-align:center;
   line-height:150px;
}
```

Comment: This can work if you always know your content is going to be `x` pixels tall.  I used this solution for a recent project and then the content ended up being of variable height and I had to switch to the `display: table-cell` solution.  ALSO This will not work if your text content is more than one line long, which is a problem I ran into.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda, just because you have height specified you can position text in the middle.

```
.imageResizeAccountInfo {
 float:left;
}
#header p {
  position relative;
  left: XXX;
  top: YYY;
}
```

Adjust XXX and YYY accordingly.

Comment: This solution is kinda brittle. It requires the elements to always be the exact same pixel-height or it will look wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to set the label to be a `display: table-cell` and then vertically align it like this:

```
#header {
 color: #333;
 width: 900px;
 float: left;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 height: 150px;
 margin: 10px 0px 5px 0px;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #CACACA 0%, #EFEFEF 100%);
    display: table;
}

#header label{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle with the result: http://jsfiddle.net/V7mYR/1/